# Wrist Rotation when Bent Over Rowing with a Barbell

Tags: weightlifting, barbell, wrist, grip, barbell-rows

Recently I included Barbell Bent Over Rows (Underhand Grip) into my workout routine. When performing them, my wrists are (pretty much) perfectly in line with my forearm at the beginning. But when I'm getting the bar closer to the end of the movement (so closer to my belly) my wrists tend to bend/rotate a little outwards.

**Is this alright or am I gripping to wide or narrow?** Im worried over damaging my wrists over time.

Comment: Does "outwards" mean your thumbs are moving closer to the side of the forearm?

Comment: @DavidScarlett Outward means, my thumbs move towards the weight-plates when performing the row with an underhand grip.

Comment: But your thumbs can't move relative to the bar if they're gripping the bar, unless your grip is slipping. Your hands are locked in position against the bar and the only possible movements of the wrist should be flexion (like a wrist curl), extension (like a reverse wrist curl), adduction (moving the little finger side of the hand closer to the side of the forearm) or abduction (moving the thumb side of the hand closer to the forearm).

Comment: @DavidScarlett Just googled what it's called. My wrist does a radial deviation when the bar gets closer to my stomach. https://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/2014/02/The-wrist.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially gripping too wide, however if this does not cause any pain or discomfort it is likely not going to affect your wrists (but best to sort it out now). It could just be potentially your form but you would have to check this online.

If you watch a form video you can see whether your form is similar and also see the wrists and grip.